# Is negative energy a consequence of gravitational energy?

Tags: gravity, potential-energy

**Assumption**

Treat all objects as a point.
Gravitational constant = 6.67384 × 10^-11 m^3 kg^-1 s^-2
Acceleration of the object is 1 ms^-2

**The setup**

Imagine there are 2 identical objects with mass of 1 Kg each is separated by a distance denoted by a letter "d". In this setup there is only a force acting on both objects and is causing both objects to accelerate towards each other, assuming no external force is involved. The force pulling both objects towards each other is the gravitational force that is acting on each other, the gravitational force is stronger when "d" is smaller. Agree so far?

**Kinetic energy**

As the object is moving we can calculate its kinetic energy, this value is positive. The faster the object moves the more kinetic energy it has.

**Potential energy**

Since both objects are separated by a distance "d", we can also calculate their potential energy and we all know that this value is negative.

**Law of conservation of energy**

This is where I'm totally lost! when two objects fall towards each other from rest, their potential energy decreases at the same time their kinetic energy increases. If the value of potential energy is negative... in order not to violet the law of conservation of energy, there must be a negative value to balance out the equation so I guess it have to be the gravitational energy.

**Question**

Q1. Is negative energy related to gravitational energy?

Q2. Is the negative energy produced in Casimir effect related to gravitational energy?

Q3. It seem quantum vacuum cannot be zero, there must be a field and can it be the hypothetical force carrier of gravity a.k.a graviton?

P.S. I have recycled the original question and posted a new one instead, therefore all comments and answers which may appears irrelevant are actually based on the old question.

Comment: well, you cannot break a system to see what would happen in that system

Comment: so just say the clocks are photons

Comment: your question is stated wrong. you have to ask "what if the limit of the speed approaches c" not "what if the speed was c". photons do not have an eigenzeit so you can not use them as clocks.

Comment: @Jimmy360 my answer is that time perceived by these two photons (atomic clocks in disguise) is still the same at the moment they are accelerated to speed of light regardless of how much time passed of outside observer (Clock C), do correct me if I misinterpret Einstein general relativity thanks.

Comment: @СимонТыран "This is a hypothetical ques..." and "suppose it  is possible to accel..."

Comment: oh, sorry, I thought you meant at a constant velocity starting at c

Comment: if you could accelerate a clock up to c its relativistic mass would get infinite (dividion by zero) and its lenght would contract to zero while its own proper time would stop, so the laws of physics would break down because you would get an infinitely high mass in an infinitely small volume.

Comment: where in nature have you seen a singularity happen?

Comment: Your question does not make more sense when one reads it more often.

Comment: In theory, if clock A and Clock B were both traveling at the speed of light, (which is impossible), but in theory, time would pass at the same rate for each clock, but time at the speed of light is confusing cause it essentially stops, and so, what's it like in stopped time? - hard to say.  The universe shrinks to a point, where trans-versing the universe takes an instant, so it's a strange and impossible scenario, but lets say you have 2 clocks traveling at the speed of light side by side - neither clock could see the other because light from 1 couldn't catch the other.

Comment: @СимонТыран/userLTK thanks for the explanation I decided to flag my question as it is inappropriate and I couldn't delete it due to an answer provided by Alfred Centauri.

Answer (score 2):

> suppose it is possible to accelerate matter at speed of light

By this you must mean *suppose that relativistic mechanics is, at its root, wrong*.

> What will the time reflects on these two clocks?

Since you've stipulated that relativistic mechanics is wrong, which incorrect, non-relativistic mechanics would you like to apply to this problem?

Comment: Yes and No, "suppose" there is a loop hole in "relativistic mechanics", if you read my question I believe there is no violation of relativity only problem is the amount of energy required to accelerate mass to attain the speed of light.

Comment: @user6760 You are denying one of the key principles of SR to see what will happen in SR. That is like asking how electricity would work without electrons.

Comment: @Jimmy360 I agreed with you so I'd flagged my question. But electricity is the flow of charged particles i.e. anti-proton and positron etc. I don't know how to delete this question any advise would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: @user6760 True, but usually when we talk about electricity we mean electrons. There should be a delete button right below the question.

Comment: I'll let the moderator do the deletion, anyway I think my questions are naive in nature but it did not violate casualty and do correct me if I'm wrong are the scientists working with particle collider actually trying to accelerate protons (not to be confused with photons) to the speed of light so that they are able to generate sufficient energy to smash particles so that they can probe the existence of a parallel universe by studying the tiny black hole if they can be found.